# Rewriting $\sin 2B$ in terms of sine and cosine functions

Tags: trigonometry

I am not a math person.

I am wondering if $\frac12 \sin 2B$ will resolve to 
$(\sin B   \cos (B + Q)) / \cos Q$.

---

Sorry, first time posting here as well as having to learn latex a little, I mistakenly edited out an earlier explanatory post. Basically I can't get from equation 2 to equation 3 and I should be able to according to the material I have referenced. The second term in braces in the second equation should be the same as the second term in the last equation but I cannot resolve it. The equation is used a lot in further material I am learning in Power Electronics. If anyone can see it I would be thankful.

Comment: $(1/2)\sin 2B = \sin B \cos B = \sin B \cos(B + 0)/\cos(0)$

Comment: thanks for reply, q is any random angle ..

Comment: based on equation 11:20 in chapter 11

Comment: of this book - http://homepages.eee.strath.ac.uk/~bwwilliams/book.htm

Comment: We have a practice on Mathematics SE that questions be self-contained. 
If you need to change your question by adding more context, please edit it and add that context. I'm not going to look at your external reference.

Comment: The expression I have written down is correct for an arbitrary value of $B$, i.e., $Q = 0$. If by $Q$ being random you mean it could take on *any* value, then the relation would not hold for arbitrary $B$.

Comment: $$\begin{align}
Vrms = [1/2\pi\int_0^b (\sqrt2V)^2 sin^2 wt\ {dwt}]^\frac{1}{2}\\
Vrms = [1/2\pi\ \{b - ( \frac{1}{2}\ sin 2b)\}]^\frac{1}{2}\\
i\ rms = (\frac{V}{Z}) = (\frac{Vcos\phi}{R}) [(\frac{1}{2\pi}\{b\ -\frac{sinb\ cos(b + \phi ))}{cos\phi }\}]^\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}$$